# Can not run kubernetes dashboard on Master node

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I installed kubernetes cluster (include one master and two nodes), and status of nodes are ready on master. When I deploy the dashboard and run it by acccessing the link `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/`, I get error

> 'dial tcp 10.32.0.2:8443: connect: connection refused' Trying to
>   reach: 'https://10.32.0.2:8443/'

The pod state of dashboard is ready, and I tried to ping to 10.32.0.2 (dashboard's ip) not succesfully

I run dashboard as the [Web UI (Dashboard)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/) guide suggests.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

There are few options here:

1. Most of the time if there is some kind of connection refused, timeout or similar error it is most likely a configuration problem. If you can't get the Dashboard running then you should try to deploy another application and try to access it. If you fail then it is not a Dashboard issue.
2. Check if you are using root/sudo.
3. Have you properly installed flannel or any other network for containers?
4. Have you checked your API logs? If not, please do so.
5. Check the description of the dashboard pod (`kubectl describe`) if there is anything suspicious.
6. Analogically check the description of service.
7. What is your cluster version? Check if any updates are required.

Please let me know if any of the above helped.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why, now I can access the dashboard. But, I tried to deploy another app: I got this error when access the link: http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/http:mysample-service:/proxy/#!/  . The error is "Error: 'dial tcp 10.40.0.3:80: connect: no route to host'
Trying to reach: 'http://10.40.0.3:80/'"  .But I can access the below link successfully: http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/mysample-service  (I run proxy before), and everything is  showed running on the kubernetes dashboard

Answer (score 0):

#### Start proxy, if it's not started

```
kubectl proxy --address='0.0.0.0' --port=8001 --accept-hosts='.*'
```

Comment: I did that before accessing dashboard link